# Check IAPs from a different application than the one they're registered to

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing, google-play-services

I have a paid app on the market with IAPs. This app is now only an unlock key for my free demo on the market. I need to make sure that the purchases from the original app transfer over to the new one. I have two ideas for this functionality.

1. I can send a bundle with the results of the purchases from the original app to the new app. Nothing wrong with that, I can use a signature protected intent to ensure security and everything should work fine.
2. I could possibly create an IABHelper with the old apps Base64-encoded RSA public key and make the query. I have not yet done this because I do not know if the key is somehow tied to the package name of the app you registered it with, and I do not have a device setup for end to end IAP testing. I was curious if anyone had any input on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 works fine, but #2 failed. The IAP key must be unique for each app, and apps will throw exceptions if you attempt to use a different key.